# Connect QB POS using PHP

Tags: php, quickbooks

There is web connector to connect QBPOS desktop with **PHP** based application but **my client doesn't like** this because of **security reasons**.

There is another way to connect QBPOS with my application, its using QBPOS SDK but this doesn't show how to connect using PHP. It has **sample code** for **C#, visual basic and QBXml**, I guess we can use QBXML but still It is missing details.

So I would **appreciate** if anybody could **suggest the way of connecting QBPOS desktop with QBPOS SDk and exchange data using PHP**. 
I dont mind if you have any other way to connect QBPOS desktop using PHP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: may this help you http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBOoks_-_Point_of_Sale_Quick-Start

Comment: the link is all about webconnector which is not liked by client.

Comment: What "security reasons" doesn't your client like?

Comment: QBPOS and web server live in same server that may add complexities to make the server secure if we use web connector. Another reason is he wants to check data  across QBPOS on real time which looks not possible through web connector.